# Why is Poe.com's Assistant able to summarize a webpage, then suddenly says it can't visit external webpages in the next message?

Tags: poe.com, behavior, summarization

Here's me getting Poe.com's Assistant to summarize (in Chinese) a news article:

> [image: Screenshot of Poe.com summarizing an article (in Chinese) about a chess.com hack https://www.hackread.com/hacker-leaks-scraped-chess-com-user-records/]

Link: https://poe.com/s/8Y5Gbw4tGUQvOJkokVlw

Worked perfectly well, so I thought I'd try it again.  Literally in the next message it says it can't visit external websites.

> [image: Screenshot of Poe.com refusing to do the same thing for an article about a Reddit father asking when he'd get his normal life back https://www.fatherly.com/life/reddit-thread-dad-life-changes-kid]

Link: https://poe.com/s/oK2wOo0xyIFm4jgKoGY2

I'm so confused.

**Question**: Why is Poe.com's Assistant able to summarize a webpage, then suddenly says it can't visit external webpages in the next message?

Comment: (By the way, if anyone else is facing this problem: you can copy/paste the full text, and it'll summarize the article.)